# what is wrong with my simple choice menu script?

Tags: bash

This is a simple script which should let me go to to directory of my choice, but its not working as intended.

```
#!/bin/bash

showMenu() {
    echo "1) ocaml"
    echo "2) python"
    echo "3) csharp"
}

while [ 1 ]
do
    showMenu
    read CHOICE
    case $CHOICE in
        "1")
            "cd ~/projects/practice/ocaml"
            ;;
        "2")
            "cd ~/projects/practice/python"
            ;;
        "3")
            "cd ~/projects/practice/csharp"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I have all the necessary folders in place:

```
(2) [01:19 PM] ls projects/practice/
csharp/  ocaml/   python/  scripts/ web/
```

Output:

```
(2) [01:19 PM] choice 
1) ocaml
2) python
3) csharp
1
/home/nanda/bin/choice: line 15: cd ~/projects/practice/ocaml: No such file or directory
1) ocaml
2) python
3) csharp
```

The script can't find the directory apparently.

I feel that I need to put the `cd` command, under each option, in some kind of substitution (with `${}` or `{}`), but I am not sure how it could be done.

Also, do I need to add a break statement after each `cd` command?

---

I should do `. choice` to make it work as intended. Better yet, I put in an alias like this and it worked:

```
alias choice='. choice'
```

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script
https://askubuntu.com/questions/84279/how-to-change-directory-using-script
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874452/change-current-directory-from-a-script

Comment: Can you confirm that you have your `projects` directory directly inside of your home directory? It is not clear from you `ls projects/practice/` output as we don't know what is your current directory when you run this. Could you change it to `ls ~/projects/practice/` output? Also, can you confirm that you run this script as the same user as when running `ls` command? And maybe you could check if replacing `~/` with full directory path fixes the problem?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the `projects` directory is inside `home`. I did `ls projects/practice` because I was already inside `home`. The script `choice` is in `~/bin`.

Comment: Then my answer below should be correct (and Julians answer too, as it's the same) and should fix your problem.

Comment: I am not sure exactly you are trying to make given the lack of details on that but I have a small recommendation if it happens to apply. I can tell that this has to do with some kind of programming and using different languages and it may be useful to add the option to manually key the dir to avoid leaving the menu.

Comment: Such as "4")     echo "Enter Custom DIR: "    read CUSDIR      cd $CUSDIR     ;;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your commands inside of quotation marks. This makes your shell treat `cd ~/projects/practice/ocaml` as a command name. As you don't have this command, it prints this error message. Files can contain space in their name so you could have command that has space in name. If you would like to run it, one way of doing it would be to use quotation marks as you did.

But you want your shell to run command `cd` and give it the path as argument. Just remote quotation marks and it should be working fine.

Whether you should or shouldn't use `break` statement in your script depends on what you want to do after changing directory. If you want to leave the loop then you should use it.

**Note** that your `cd` command in shell script won't change current directory after running this script. It will only affect current directory inside of the script (unless you use `source` instead of running it) since when you run the script, new process is created and `cd` only affects current directory in current and child processes, not in parent one.

Comment: I removed the quotes around `"cd ~/projects/practice/ocaml"`. Now if I enter any option, it is not throwing any error, but its not going any where either. I mean I am still stuck in the while loop.

Comment: @Nanda: Your while loop is endless so you won't go anyware. You can add `pwd` command at the end of the loop to see that the current directory has changed. Or you can use `break` statement to leave the loop (so yes, you should use break statement for this case).

Comment: I did add the `pwd` command, it is indeed going into the intended directory, but it is still in the loop. So, if I break the loop with ^C, I am still where I was originally. So I put `break;;` and it came out of the loop. But to my surprise, when I do `pwd` after coming out of the loop, I still am where I started the script from.

Comment: @Nanda: Read the note at the end of my answer.

Comment: After sourcing, it worked. So basically all I have to do is either `source choice` or `. choice`. Thanks Krzysztof.

Comment: @Nanda: Just keep in mind what sourcing your script means and what problems it can make. It basically runs all the lines of your script inside of your bash so it may change your environment etc.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you for the direction.

Comment: You could add an exit option like this, RUN=1     while [ $RUN ]   do    case $CHOICE in     "5")     export RUN=0   ;;

Comment: @Joe: Just note that export is not needed to set RUN=0. Indeed is better not to use it since we don't want to pollute environment of newly created processes. Especially since OP sources this script instead of running it as a new process.

Comment: Just a habit as I do most things from the terminal instead of a shell script as my system changes hourly sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

This situation is exactly what the shell's `select` statement is for:

```
select choice in ocaml python csharp; do
    case $choice in
        ocaml|python|csharp) break ;;
    esac
done
echo cd ~/projects/practice/$choice
```

Slightly DRYer:

```
choices=(ocaml python csharp)
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    [[ " ${choices[*]} " == *" $choice "* ]] && break
done
echo cd ~/projects/practice/$choice
```

Comment: +1; slightly OT: DRY?

Comment: [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 3):

You have quotes around the cd command.
Remove those and you should be fine.

```
"cd ~/projects/practice/ocaml"
```

says run that command - the whole string, so it will look for such a command, including the space and the ~ and everything.

You want the command to be cd with an argument of the directory.